# Is it safe to use Task.Delay for a delay of 24 houers

Tags: c#, async-await

Is it safe to use `Task.Delay()` for a delay of 24 houers in a loop to run code every day?
My code is:

```cs
while (!token.IsCancellationRequested) 
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromDays(1), token);
    await DoStuff(token);
}
```

Is it safe to use `Task.Delay()` in that fashion?

Comment: 1 day delay? it's better to use Task Scheduler for this ... also where? if it's a mobile app (Xamarin/Unity) then it doesn't make sens

Comment: It is in asp.net-core with .net-core 3.1

Comment: you should do some research ... and use some already existing libraries ... as prolly process will not stand so long

Comment: If your code resides inside a fire-and-forget `Task`, you may find this interesting: [Fire and forget on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Including some context from your comment, no, this is not a safe approach with ASP.net Core, as it's very likely that your process will be recycled long before 24 hours is reached.

For functionality like this, you really should look at a scheduler that is designed to persist state to a database of some sort and have a longer lifetime than the web hosting core generally does.

Hangfire is a pretty complete implementation of what you're looking for, take a look at https://www.hangfire.io/.

If you're interested in building something yourself, I'd suggest a hosted service which has gotten a lot of love in .NET Core 3+ and is really extremely solid now.  Here's Microsoft's docs on it (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) and there's a nice blog post here that gives a good walkthrough with a specific example (https://wakeupandcode.com/worker-service-in-asp-net-core/)

The general pattern you'd want here would be to have a service that checks a table of upcoming tasks every X minutes and runs the necessary task if it's past it's due time.  Then, your code above would just need to be adapted to put a row in your table with the due time of your DoStuff() function.

Comment: I second the hangfire recommendation, worked well when I'ave used it like this.